# How to access changeset without data access?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I want to ask a serious concern due to data privacy. As I have to work from outside country and due to data protection production user data is not allowed to share with me as I have stay outside country.

I have to do deployment on production on different stages. Now the question is, possible to have only deployment feature via changeset so that I should not have access to data but only the changeset on salesforce production? I think I should not have administrator rights but then how can I access changeset?

What are the possible solutions to this problem so that data privacy should be in place and the development work should be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Request a dataless developer sandbox.

In developer sandboxes you can be an admin and prepare packages, as well as outbound change sets.